# Using an existing database in Ionic - Visual Studio 2017 mobile app

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic2, visual-studio-2017, typescript2.0

I have created a database using [DB Browser For SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) called `data.db` with the file is saved in the directory `www/`

Here is my `home.ts` file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, NavController, NavParams, ViewController, PopoverController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SQLite } from "ionic-native";
import { RatesPage } from '../rates/rates';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    public itemList: Array<Object>;
    public database: SQLite;
    constructor(public popoverCtrl: PopoverController, public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform) {
        this.itemList = [];

        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.database = new SQLite();
            this.database.openDatabase({
                name: "data.db",
                location: "default"
            }).then((data) => {
                this.database.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT)", {})
                    .then((data) => {
                        console.log("TABLE CREATED: ", data);
                        alert('db and table created ');
                    }, (error) => {
                        alert("Unable to execute sql " + error);
                    })
            }, (error) => {
                alert("Unable to open database " + error);
            });
        });
    }
 }
```

I have used this [link](https://www.addwebsolution.com/blog/know-how-use-sqlite-ionic-2) to help me.

I do not understand why I have to create a table while i'm including a full database?

Comment: what is an "exiting database"?

Comment: I created a database using DB Browser for SQLite and saved the database in a file called data.db that is what i mean by an existing database. i do not want to create all the tables in the code. i want to use the already "existing" database that i have already crated in the data.db file

Comment: here is a screenshot of the file inside the project: http://imgur.com/a/ScqG7

Comment: is the database maybe empty? So it doesnt have that table yet?

Comment: I'm sure it's not empty.

Comment: I'm using now cordova-sqlite-ext which actually supports Prepopulated database. but still it is not opening the database